# Canon_MF731C_733C Does not accept jobs - 17.10

Tags: printing, canon, cups-lpd

I recently did a fresh install of 17.10.

Prior to the installation, this printer worked like a charm.

I am connected via WiFi. Now I can print from the Chrome browser but nothing else.

As can be seen in the image provided the printer is recognized but does not function from other apps. I have yet to find any crumbs to lead me to a solution to this peculiarity. Any suggestions or ideas?

Is this the correct place to post this type of inquiry?

[image: Printer does not accept jobs]

Answer (score 0):

I booted from a thumb drive and which had Ubuntu-MATE 17.10 and found that I had the same problem. I turned off the printer and unplugged it then turn it back on and the problem was resolved. However, I still see the "Does not accept jobs" message as depicted above but the printer is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing the driver that Canon supply for this device; they updated it on the 8th Feb 2018 to cope with Ubuntu 17.10 so if you go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100924010.html and click to download and SAVE what will be linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz and it should end up in your Downloads folder; so if you open a terminal; copy each command below; line by line; paste each line into the terminal; hit the ENTER key; then move to the next line

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz
cd linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken
```

then one runs the install script; please watch it work as it will ask you questions;

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

so that should 1) install the drivers and 2) register the printer so it appears in your PRINTERS folder; if you delete any entries there for the MFC before you run the above commands; so you are removing entries that you say do not work; let us know how it goes